# Vertical alignment when using pictures in multirow

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, align, multirow, multicolumn

I wrote the following table using multirow

[image]

Although as far as I know multirow should automatically do the vertical alignment, for me this happens only as long as I don't include pictures. 
What I am trying to do is the vertical centering of the content of the cells in the first column. Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this issue?
The code is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow,graphics,graphicx}
usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{c|m{1.5cm}m{2cm}l} 
MR & GS & Typ & Sym \\ \hline
\multirow{4}*{ 1} & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{F1} & Tria&                        \\  
               & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{F1} & Obl           &            \\ 
                   & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{F1} & Sq            &            \\                    & \includegraphics[width=1cm,     height=1cm]{F1} & Rec   &            \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{2} & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{F1} &     SqSnSq       &            \\ 
                   & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{F1} &     TrHex     &            \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{3} & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{F1} &     TrKag        &            \\ 
                   & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{F1} &     RecShSq&            \\ 
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See 3.8 Dealing with tall entries in the documentation of multirow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's easier not to use `multirow` and just use a nested tabular to the right, as `tabular` are vertically centred by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow,graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{c|l} 
MR & 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{1cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}@{}}GS & Typ & Sym\end{tabular}
\\ \midrule
1 &
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{1cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}@{}}
 \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} & Tria&                        \\  
 \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} & Obl           &            \\ 
 \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} & Sq            & \\
 \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} & Rec   &  
\end{tabular}
    \\ \midrule
2 & 
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{1cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}@{}}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} &     SqSnSq       &            \\ 
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} &     TrHex     & 
\end{tabular}
    \\ \midrule
3 &
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{1cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}@{}}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} &     TrKag        &            \\ 
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} &     RecShSq&       
\end{tabular}
\\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know whether this is the **best** solution, but you could use the `vpos` and `vmove` optional parameters of the `multirow` commands, as seen below

Roughly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{c|m{1.5cm}m{2cm}l} 
MR & GS & Typ & Sym \\ \hline
\multirow[c]{4}{*}[-1cm]{1} & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{imma}& Tria&\\ 
               & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{imma} & Obl&    \\ 
                   & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{imma} & Sq & \\                    & \includegraphics[width=1cm,     height=1cm]{imma} & Rec   &            \\ \hline
\multirow[c]{2}{*}[-0.4cm]{2} & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{imma} &     SqSnSq       &            \\ 
                   & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{imma} &     TrHex     &            \\ \hline
\multirow[c]{2}{*}[-0.4cm]{3} & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{imma} &     TrKag        &            \\ 
                   & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{imma} &     RecShSq&            \\ 
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Yielding:

[image]

Basically the syntax you would use is `\multirow[vpos]{x}{*}[-y]{T}`
where:

- *vpos* is either `b` (bottom), `c` (centre), or `t` top
- *x* is the number of columns to span
- *y* is the **vertical adjustment** to insert. I put a minus before it because you have to move things down.
- *T* is the text of your multirow.

**ALSO** please mark that `graphics` is superseded by `graphicx` thus is no more needed

Answer (score 3):

Moriambar’s solution is good, under the assumption that `\multirow` should be used.

Here's a different solution, under the assumption that empty cells denote repetition of the value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}

\begin{tabular}{ccll}
\toprule
MR & GS & Typ & Sym \\
\midrule
1 & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image} & Tria    &  \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image} & Obl     &  \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image} & Sq      &  \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image} & Rec     &  \\
\midrule
2 & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image} & SqSnSq  &  \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image} & TrHex   &  \\
\midrule
3 & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image} & TrKag   &  \\
\addlinespace[2pt]
  & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image} & RecShSq &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]